# OpenCV How to find seam lines in an image?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

After the InRange and GaussianBlur function, I get the following image:

[image]

I find the edges and I get:

[image]

I need to get from this image three lines, which are represented in the following image (lines that are not red are bulging nodes):

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: skeletonize your image

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Erosion operation with a clever structuring element.
I suggest to use one with the length of the longest horizontal line to remove.

I've made a little example:

Let's take this [toErode.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM16M.png)

```
        double longestHorLine = 201;
        Image<Gray, byte> toErode = new Image<Gray, byte>(path+ "toErode.png");
        for(int i =1;i<4;i++)
        {
            Mat element = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size((int)(longestHorLine / i), 3), new Point(-1, -1));
            CvInvoke.Erode(toErode, toErode, element, new Point(-1, -1), i, BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar(0));
            toErode.Save(path + "res"+i+".png");
        }
```

Which produces the following outputs: [res1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wxp.png) ,[res2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blZT1.png) and 
[res3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnBrR.png)